# Eclipse rcp export product throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, exe, rcp

I have eclipse rcp project, I want to export it and make executable. I do `Export an Eclipse product` via product file. As result I get catalog with plugins, other files and `MyApp.exe` but when I run exe file, In log I get such message. Maybe someone can tell me what could be the reason of this exception?

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2016-09-18 15:05:10.837
!MESSAGE Product myapp.product could not be found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-09-18 14:06:41.616
    !MESSAGE Application error
    !STACK 1
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI$URIPool$PlatformAccessUnit.setValue(URI.java:865)
        at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI$URIPool.intern(URI.java:1949)
        at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI.createPlatformPluginURI(URI.java:2718)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.determineApplicationModelURI(E4Application.java:407)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:348)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:252)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

Comment: `Product myapp.product could not be found` is the key message here - your exported product doesn't seem to contain your product definition (perhaps the plugin is missing). The crash is caused because the product couldn't be found.

Comment: hello, thank you for answer, what kind of plugin is missing?

Comment: Well probably the plugin where you define your product `myapp.product` in the plugin.xml. Look at your `xxx.product` file and make sure that all your plugins are listed plus all the required Eclipse RCP plugins.

Comment: ow thank you, just needed to add plugin with the same name as project ID,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Product myapp.product could not be found` is the key message here - your exported product doesn't seem to contain your product definition (perhaps the plugin is missing). The crash is caused because the product couldn't be found.

Make sure that your `xxx.product` file contains all your plugins plus all the Eclipse RCP plugins that they depend on (you can use the 'Add Required' button to work this out).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problems, when following the tutorial from [vogella](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html)

Make sure the plugin defining your product "myapp.product" is also included in the product configuration. So, if your product configuration is based on features, you need to add the "myapp.product" plugin inside a feature. Otherwise, it is not part of the packaging.

See [Maven Tycho RCP Product Not Found After Moving Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51994067/maven-tycho-rcp-product-not-found-after-moving-folder/59665104#59665104)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same exact error and was initially misled by the "product not found error message". After tracing the stacktrace and the Eclipse source code I realized that when I dropped my Application.e4xmi into the ui plugin project I hadn't added it to the build.properties file so that it would get packaged in the jar. Once I did that it worked as expected.