# Maven Tycho RCP Product Not Found After Moving Folder

Tags: maven, runtime-error, eclipse-rcp, tycho

Following the [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html#exercise-tycho-build-for-products) Maven-Tycho tutorial, I have ran into a runtime error.

After exporting my project I am unable to launch it. The following error occurs after my headless build, and also after an eclipse export wizard build.

It triggers the following runtime error:

```
!SESSION 2018-08-23 13:42:44.875 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_181
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -clearPersistedState
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -clearPersistedState

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2018-08-23 13:42:47.327
!MESSAGE Product com.vogella.tycho.rcp.product could not be found.
```

I believe this might be triggered because the tutorial has you move the rcp.product file into a new directory. I have already tried to go to Run -> Run Configurations and have added the rcp plugin.

Here is my project structure. The missing product file was moved from ./bundles/com.voglla.tycho.rcp/ -> ./releng/com.vogella.tycho.product/

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mtZD.png)

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: In the `pom.xml` files did you adapt the relative paths in the `<relativePath>` and `<module>` elements?

Comment: @howlger That's what I thought it might have to do with. Which pom file would have the relative path to the .product?

Comment: In the tutorial, the product is included via the root `/pom.xml` containing `<module>releng</module>` and `/releng/pom.xml` containing`<module>com.vogella.tycho.product</module>`. What exactly do you mean by _"After exporting my project"_? Did you build the product via Tycho or via the Eclipse export wizard?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the "com.vogella.tycho.rcp" plug-in to the feature "com.vogella.tycho.feature".
That is, the feature should contain both com.vogella.tycho.plugin1 & com.vogella.tycho.rcp.

The com.vogella.tycho.rcp plugin was missing, since the product is configured to be based on features, and that missing plugin is not part of a feature.

So this is a bug in the instructions, but it is unfortunate that one cannot make comments on the original site http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html#exercise-tycho-build-for-products.